# Drupal 6 - Services 3 - Image Upload

Tags: image, rest, service, drupal-6, multipartform-data

I'm using Services 3 to create a custom service that will create or update a specific content type (similar to the built-in Node Service).  The content type uses CCK for a few fields, mainly an image (file) upload field.  I have no problem connecting to the service and creating a new node by setting the text parameters (including some CCK fields), but I can't figure out how to handle submitting a file.

I've tried base64 encoding the jpg then passing it as a parameter using the same field name as the node creation form uses, files[field_um_high_res_0].  I've also tried submitting a multipart form.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Howie

Answer (score 2):

Looks like all I had to do was encode the file as base64 then use the file resource to create a new file in the system and take the resultant fid and use it to load the new file object which is passed as the value of the CCK file field.

So it looks like this:

```
my_cck_file_field_name[0] = the_file_object
```